# Items after dropping from widget to widget missing

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qlistwidget

After dragging and dropping an item from a list widget to a list widget, the item disappears in the target list widget.

I used eventFilter for only the list widgets in MainWindow.

```cpp
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *target,QEvent *event){
    if (event->type() == QEvent::DragEnter)
       {
          QDragEnterEvent *tDragEnterEvent = static_cast<QDragEnterEvent *>(event);
          tDragEnterEvent->acceptProposedAction();

          return true;
       }
       else if (event->type() == QEvent::DragMove)
       {
          QDragMoveEvent *tDragMoveEvent = static_cast<QDragMoveEvent *>(event);
          tDragMoveEvent->acceptProposedAction();

          return true;
       }
        else if (event->type() == QEvent::Drop)
       {
          QDropEvent *tDropEvent = static_cast<QDropEvent *>(event);
          tDropEvent->acceptProposedAction();

          qDebug() << "OK, execute your task!";

          return true;
       }
       else
       {
           // standard event processing
           return QObject::eventFilter(target, event);
       }


    //return false;
}
//in MainWindow constructor
ui->listWidget->installEventFilter(this);
```

qDebug showed the debug line but the item went missing.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see more code in order to understand your problem. However, if you goal is related to drag and drop support, then it might be possible you do not need event filter logic at all. Through Qt Creator, you can set for both [QListWidget](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html) instances the following properties:

1. dragEnabled set to true.
2. dragDropMode set to DragDrop.
3. defaultDropAction set to MoveAction.

See the image below:

[image]

Another way to set these properties is through code:

```
// Assuming listWidget points to instance of the QListWidget
listWidget->setDragEnabled(true);
listWidget->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragDrop);
listWidget->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
```